# Delete all files with extension .c using shell command in vba

Tags: vba, excel, shell

i want to delete all files with extension ".c" in a folder from shell command in vba, below code i am not able to execute in VBA Macro. should there be any issue if folder name contains spaces in it or what changes should be done in code

```
all_C_Files = Selected_User_Output_Folder & "*.C"
Shell "cmd /c del /F" & all_C_Files 

'Selected_User_Output_Folder = "C:\Users\Berater\Desktop\Config File Generator"
```

Comment: try the command in the cmd window first. it is pointless to do anything in vba until it works at a command prompt.

Comment: Try with `Kill Selected_User_Output_Folder  & "\*.C"`

Comment: Paths with spaces need to be quoted.

Comment: Also you've left no space between  `/F` and the folder path

Answer (score 1):

Why to use shell command at all when you can use Kill

```
Sub test()
    Selected_User_Output_Folder = "C:\Users\Berater\Desktop\Config File Generator\*.c"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill Selected_User_Output_Folder
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Always good practice to quote file/folder paths:

```
all_C_Files = Selected_User_Output_Folder & "*.C"
Shell "cmd /c del /F """ & all_C_Files & """"
```

Comment: If Dir(all_C_Files) <> "" Then                                                                
        Shell "cmd /S /C del /F " & Chr(34) & all_C_Files & Chr(34)
    End If

This worked for me